# Reference for properties of strict/proper transform?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It looks like this question has already been asked, but after reading some mistitled previous questions you can see it actually doesn't appear in the "Related Questions" list.

Is there a reference for properties preserved by the strict/proper transform?

I am looking for statements like: "If $f: Y \to X$ has property (P) and $\mathcal{I}$ is a sheaf of ideals on $X$ then the canonical morphism $Bl_{f^{-1}\mathcal{I} \cdot {{\mathcal{O}}Y}} Y \to Bl_\mathcal{I} X$ has property (P)."

The case where (P) is flat, proper, or a closed immersion are all treated in Hartshorne or Liu but I was surprised that I had difficulty finding a list of properties like this in EGA.

Edit: The particular property I'm looking for at the moment is finiteness, but the more general question for various other properties seems to come up quite often for me.

Edit 2: Finiteness follows from $Bl\ Y$ being a closed subscheme of $Y \times_X Bl\ X$. I'm still interested in the original question though.

Comment: By the way, I would not call $f^{-1}I \cdot \mathcal{O}_Y$ the strict or proper transform of $I$.  Sometimes I've seen it called the *total transform*.

Comment: In the case where $f$ is a closed immersion Hartshorne and Liu both call it the strict transform (page 165 and 324 resp). 

Comment: Actually, maybe I was ambiguous in the question. By strict transform I am referring to the morphism $Bl\ Y \to Bl\ X$, not the closed subscheme of $Bl\ X$ corresponding to $p^{-1}\mathcal{I} \cdot \mathcal{O}_X$ where $p: Bl\ X \to X$. I think I've seen this latter called the total transform somewhere, maybe in Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: @name, generally speaking in my experience people talk about strict transforms of closed subvarieties, not morphisms.  This is why I was confused, sorry about that.  I understand the way you are using it now.  

Your $f$ is not necessarily a closed immersion, right?

Comment: @Karl, Sorry for having been ambiguous.

No, my morphism $f$ is not necassarily a closed immersion, but I believe the terminology is still used, although a definition in the literature escapes me at present (Définition 5.1.1(ii) of Raynaud-Gruson's article "Critères de platitude et de projectivité" is the best I can find; also incidentally, applications of Section 5.2 are what motivated the question).